# How does radix sort work for a list of single digit numbers?

Tags: sorting, radix-sort

I learnt radix sort works by sorting the numbers according to the digits in unit place and then tens place and so on.
The list gets sorted after nth pass when the maximum number of digits is n.
But will it work for a list of single digit numbers? If yes, how?

Edit:
Sorting 1 53 20 359 12 will follow these steps.
PASS 1:
Stack 0-20
Stack 1-1
Stack 2-12
Stack 3-53
Stack 4-
Stack 5-
Stack 6-
Stack 7-
Stack 8-
Stack 9-359
20 1 12 53 359
PASS 2:
Stack 0-1
Stack 1-12
Stack 2-20
Stack 3-
Stack 4-
Stack 5-53 359
Stack 6-
Stack 7-
Stack 8-
Stack 9-
1 12 20 53 359
PASS 3:
It's already sorted.

But how will it work for this list?
7 3 2 5 3 1 0?

Comment: How do you think it will work? `n = 1` is just as valid as `n = 8`.

Comment: I've edited my question.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. You seem to be dancing around the obvious answer because you don't believe it.

Comment: No I don't understand how it will work.
PASS 1:
Stack 0-7 3 2 5 3 1 0
Right? How will it get sorted?

Comment: Why would you put all of those numbers in the same stack when the digits are all different?

Comment: I'm sorry. I misunderstood. Thanks :)

Comment: Seems like a valid question that was misunderstood by beaker. Doesn't seem like it was ever properly answered, and Subramanian just gave up trying to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a base 10 decimal system, and sorting each digit from least significant to most, Radix Sort would start by sorting digits in the 1's column (10 ^ 0), 10's column (10 ^ 1), 100's column (10 ^ 2), and so on.

To answer your question more succinctly, if you have 10 buckets (arrays) that you are sorting to in each pass, the single digits would get sorted first.

So for example, if an array with all single digits is passed into Radix Sort:

```
[5, 8, 3, 2, 7, 1]
```

The resulting output for each bucket would look something like this:

```
[[], [ 1 ], [ 2 ], [ 3 ], [], [ 5 ], [], [ 7 ], [ 8 ], []]
```

What would follow after this pass, (or before each subsequent pass in the event that there are more digits) is the array would be flattened in the order that they have in their respective buckets, with a method like .concat().

So, if you added a couple 2-digit numbers in there:

```
[5, 8, 13, 2, 41, 1];
```

It would look something like this:

```
[[], [41, 1], [2], [13], [], [5], [], [], [8], []] // first pass, 1's

[41, 1, 2, 13, 5, 8] // flattened; all single digits are sorted on this pass.


[[1, 2, 5, 8 ], [13], [], [], [41], [], [], [], [], []] // second pass, 10's
[1, 2, 5, 8, 13, 41] // flattened; array is now sorted and returned.
```

Hope this helps. I also had wondered this same thing when I first tackled this problem.